# OS X, How to edit a file in var/root folder

Tags: macos

I've a file named config.properties in the var root folder. How do I edit this file and save it.

Every where it says to type this in terminal, it will open a text editor with admin access. But, its not opening for me

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

I've searching for how to do this for some time and I'm really tired, not finding a solution. Can someone be kind enough to help me?

Comment: Is this about programming? If not, I think it would be a better fit on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like that to open file in TextEdit:

```
sudo open -e /var/tmp/mobile_installation.log.0
```

Additionally you can use any other text editor which can work with file rights correctly. I prefer [Fraise](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33751/fraise) editor.